# Revelando os caracteres certos - jogo da forca

Tags: python-3.x

Estou criando as funções antes de montar o jogo em si, e travei na parte de revelar os caracteres. Na minha função, eu quero receber uma palavra em string, essa mesma palavra oculta no formato ' ___ ' e uma letra.
Com isso eu recebo a string com os valores revelados, mas ela só revela o primeiro índice com a letra certa. Como eu posso consertar isso?

```
def revelando(string, string_oculta, letra):

    for i in range(len(string)): 
    if string[i] in letra:
        return  string_oculta[:i] +string[i] + string_oculta[i+1:]
```

o que esta acontecendo:

entrada: revelando('amar',['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ '], 'a')

retorno: ['a', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ']

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
palavra = "amar"


def jogo_forca():
    letras_ocultas = ["_"] * len(palavra) # Troca as letras por "_".
    palavra_para_letras = list(palavra) # Cria uma lista com as letras da palavra.
    usadas = [] # Lista com as letras que já foram usadas pra não ficar sem mostrar nada.
    while palavra_para_letras.count("$") != len(palavra): # Enquanto ainda houver letras e não $ vai continuar pedindo.
        print(f"|- {''.join(letras_ocultas)}") # Mostra a palavra atualizada mas como str e não como lista
        print("__--__" * 10) # Perfumaria pra não ficar tudo junto.
        letra = input("Digite uma letra: ") # Pede a letra .
        if letra not in usadas: # Verifica se a letra já não foi usada, se foi mostra a mensagem e volta a pedir uma letra. 
            usadas.append(letra)
        else:
            print(f"A {letra} já foi usada")
            continue        
        quantidade_letras = palavra_para_letras.count(letra) # Pega a quantidade de vezes que a letra está dentro da lista exemplo amar = 2.
        if quantidade_letras: # Verifica se a há alguma letra como no python 0 == False eu não preciso colocar > 0 pois se for 0 é Falso.
            for _ in range(quantidade_letras): # roda o loop pela quantidade de letras que foi encontrada na palavra exemplo: se usar a letra "a" vai fazer o loop 2x.
                index = palavra_para_letras.index(letra) # Pega o index que a letra aparece exemplo : letra "a" vai pegar o index 0 no primeiro loop e 2 no segundo AMAR -> 0123.
                palavra_para_letras[index] = "$" # Troca a letra por "$" assim fica mais fácil ter um controle, pois se apagar muda o index da lista.
                letras_ocultas[index] = letra # Troca "_" pela letra encontrada

    print(f"Parabéns você acertou a palavra: {palavra}") # Fim do While e acaba o programa.
        




jogo_forca()
```

Não tive muito tempo de testar mas acredito que isso possa te dar uma luz.

Comment: Você precisa colocar uma letra ou um atalho pra parar o while.

Comment: caraca, ficou muito bom! muito obrigada!